# Persisting data if none exists for a certain key using AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage, data-persistence

I'm trying to set up a function where I first check to see if I have a value for a certain key, and if I do not, I use the axios library to get a value from the web and persist it as that key's value instead. Here is my code:

```
async getName() {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('dummy'); //the value should be a JSON object
        if (value !== null){
            return value.name;
        }
        else {
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/dummy')
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    try {
                        await AsyncStorage.setItem('dummy', 'dummyval');
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    return(response.name);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error fetching name: ' + error.response);
                });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

I'm pretty new to React Native, so I'm sure this looks like a mess. I know I must be doing something wrong because I keep getting a syntax error on the second use of await. Does anyone know how to properly structure these calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `axios`'s success handler using `async` keyword. In your code, you have written like `.then(function (response)`, this should be changed to `.then(async function (response)`.

Consider following changes.

```
async getName() {
 try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('dummy'); //the value should be a JSON object
    if (value !== null){
        return value.name;
    }
    else {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/dummy')
            .then(async function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('dummy', 'dummyval');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                return(response.name);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error fetching name: ' + error.response);
            });
    }
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I think that worked! Might I ask one more question? I'm trying to put the result of this function into a Text div like so <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.getName()}</Text>, but I keep getting an error saying 'objects are not valid as a react child'. When I print the return value to console it seems to be a valid string. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Use `state` to store the response, and use it in your `Text`. Like, When response received use `this.setState({value: respone})`, and in the `render` method try `<Text>{this.state.value}</Text>`.
So, instead of returning value from `getName`, store the value in `state`.